# get the value from dictionary

Tags: python

I have a text file and it includes dictionaries, I want to get the value for all the Swiss-Prot and print them in separate lines.

For example, I want them to be like this as two column of query and swiss-prot

```
Query  Swiss-Prot

MED13  Q9UHV7

NIPBL  Q6KC79
```

This is a short example of the text type:

```
[{"query": "MED13", "_id": "9969", "_score": 89.814735, "uniprot": {"Swiss-Prot": "Q9UHV7", "TrEMBL": ["J3QRB7", "A0A024QZ75"]}}, {"query": "NIPBL", "_id": "25836", "_score": 90.15312, "uniprot": {"Swiss-Prot": "Q6KC79", "TrEMBL": ["H0Y8M3", "A0A590UJS4"]}}, {"query": "XPO1", "_id": "7514", "_score": 90.00326, "uniprot": {"Swiss-Prot": "O14980", "TrEMBL": ["A0A7I2V461", "A0A7I2V2Y6", "A0A7I2V6B9", "B3KWD0", "A0A7I2V396", "A0A7I2V531", "C9J673", "A0A7I2V3P3", "A0A7I2V3J1", "A0A7I2V2H0", "A0A7I2YQV4", "C9IYM2", "A0A7I2YQP1", "A0A7I2V3N0", "A0A7I2V2S3", "C9JKM9", "A0A7I2V3W6", "A0A7P0Z4B7", "A0A7I2V2C5", "A0A7I2V4A3", "F8WF71", "A0A7I2V488", "A0A7I2YQX3"]}}, {"query": "PRR12", "_id": "57479", "_score": 93.08752, "uniprot": {"Swiss-Prot": "Q9ULL5"}}, {"query": "USP9X", "_id": "8239", "_score": 91.546684, "uniprot": {"Swiss-Prot": "Q93008", "TrEMBL": ["Q86X58", "Q6P468"]}}, {"query": "POLA1", "_id": "5422", "_score": 87.691986, "uniprot": {"Swiss-Prot": "P09884", "TrEMBL": ["A0A5F9ZHW2", "A6NMQ1", "A0A7I2V2V3"]}}, {"query": "SYNGAP1", "_id": "8831", "_score": 92.250496, "uniprot": {"Swiss-Prot": "Q96PV0", "TrEMBL": ["B7ZCA0", "A0A1U9X8L0", "A0A2R8YDS2", "A0A1B0GW70", "A0A140T8W4", "A0A0A0MQZ2", "A0A2R8Y6T2", "A0A804HJ92"]}}, {"query": "PRKDC", "_id": "5591", "_score": 87.73935, "uniprot": {"Swiss-Prot": "P78527", "TrEMBL": ["F5GX40", "H0YG84"]}}, {"query": "HDAC4", "_id": "9759", "_score": 87.96423, "uniprot": {"Swiss-Prot": "P56524", "TrEMBL": ["H7C397", "A0A7I2SVS4", "C9J0X4", "H7BZT3", "C9J481"]}}, {"query": "SMG1", "_id": "23049", "_score": 87.58261, "uniprot": {"Swiss-Prot": "Q96Q15", "TrEMBL": ["H3BR09", "I3L400", "J3KRA9", "H3BPS6", "A0A087X1K8", "I3L0W2", "E9PNP6", "I3L144", "H3BQN7"]}}, {"query": "ZC3H4", "_id": "23211", "_score": 88.41728, "uniprot": {"Swiss-Prot": "Q9UPT8", "TrEMBL": "M0QY97"}}, {"query": "COL5A1", "_id": "1289", "_score": 88.062645, "uniprot": {"Swiss-Prot": "P20908", "TrEMBL": ["B2ZZ86", "A0A024R8E5", "Q59EE7", "H7BY82"]}}, {"query": "SMARCA4", "_id": "6597", "_score": 91.729965, "uniprot": {"Swiss-Prot": "P51532", "TrEMBL": ["A7E2E1", "Q9HBD4", "B3KNW7", "A0A2R8Y7S2", "A0A2R8YF80", "A0A2R8Y523", "A0A2R8Y6N0", "A0A2R8Y583", "A0A2R8Y7Y7", "A0A2R8Y7R0", "A0A2R8Y440", "A0A2R8YGP5", "A0A2R8Y866", "A0A2R8YFK5", "A0A2R8YDA1", "A0A2R8YF38", "K7EP28", "A0A2R8Y526", "A0A2R8Y5K3", "A0A2R8YFV8", "A0A2R8YF58", "A0A2R8YGG3", "A0A2R8Y7F3", "K7EQF0", "A0A2R8YG32", "A0A2R8Y4P4", "A0A2R8Y4C5", "A0A2R8YCY3", "A0A2R8Y6V2", "A0A2R8Y4R6"]}}, {"query": "TNPO1", "_id": "3842", "_score": 87.91549, "uniprot": {"Swiss-Prot": "Q92973", "TrEMBL": ["E7EW37", "A0A024RAM0", "A0A7P0T9C0", "S4R398", "A0A7P0T944", "A0A7P0TBF0", "A0A7P0Z4D3"]}}, {"query": "AGO1", "_id": "26523", "_score": 91.19263, "uniprot": {"Swiss-Prot": "Q9UL18", "TrEMBL": ["B2RAD8", "Q5TA58", "A0A6I8PTZ8", "B3KME0", "A0A0U1RQZ8"]}}, {"query": "ARHGAP35", "_id": "2909", "_score": 90.83041, "uniprot": {"Swiss-Prot": "Q9NRY4"}}, {"query": "LRP1", "_id": "4035", "_score": 90.87773, "uniprot": {"Swiss-Prot": "Q07954", "TrEMBL": ["Q6PJ72", "Q59FG2", "Q7Z7K9", "H0YJ88", "H0YJI8"]}}, {"query": "TOP1", "_id": "7150", "_score": 88.75276, "uniprot": {"Swiss-Prot": "P11387", "TrEMBL": ["A0A7P0T852", "Q9BVT2", "A0A7P0T9R7"]}}, {"query": "TRIP12", "_id": "9320", "_score": 87.6137, "uniprot": {"Swiss-Prot": "Q14669", "TrEMBL": ["A0A6Q8PGG9", "A0A6Q8PHK0", "G5E9G6", "C9JSX9", "C9JLJ5", "C9JLD7", "H7C1L9", "H7C2Y1", "F8W9P3"]}}, {"query": "KMT2E", "_id": "55904", "_score": 87.338264, "uniprot": {"Swiss-Prot": "Q8IZD2", "TrEMBL": ["C9JNE1", "A0A087WYW5", "S4R363", "C9JQ68", "H7C5C4", "A0A590UK87", "H7C4F3", "C9JYI9", "F8WAU9"]}}, {"query": "HCFC1", "_id": "3054", "_score": 92.59821, "uniprot": {"Swiss-Prot": "P51610", "TrEMBL": ["H7C1C4", "A6NEM2"]}}, {"query": "UBTF", "_id": "7343", "_score": 88.12895, "uniprot": {"Swiss-Prot": "P17480", "TrEMBL": ["E9PLT2", "E9PKP7", "H0YDH7", "E9PMM2"]}}, {"query": "HUWE1", "_id": "10075", "_score": 88.91688, "uniprot": {"Swiss-Prot": "Q7Z6Z7", "TrEMBL": ["A0A1B0GXC7", "A0A024R9W5", "H0Y659", "A0A087X146", "A0A087X1S3"]}}, {"query": "KDM3B", "_id": "51780", "_score": 87.94795, "uniprot": {"Swiss-Prot": "Q7LBC6", "TrEMBL": ["H0Y946", "H0Y9V5"]}}, {"query": "TRRAP", "_id": "8295", "_score": 90.83041, "uniprot": {"Swiss-Prot": "Q9Y4A5", "TrEMBL": ["A0A2R8YFJ4", "F2Z2U4", "C9K0N1", "H0Y4W2"]}}, {"query": "GRIN2B", "_id": "2904", "_score": 89.35281, "uniprot": {"Swiss-Prot": "Q13224", "TrEMBL": ["A0A1B0GU78", "A0A0D9SFK0", "A0A0D9SFA0"]}}, {"query": "USP7", "_id": "7874", "_score": 87.70774, "uniprot": {"Swiss-Prot": "Q93009", "TrEMBL": ["B7ZAX6", "B7Z855", "Q6U8A4", "I3L2D8", "H3BVA7", "H3BQD1", "H3BRI4", "F5H2X1", "H3BTM1", "H3BND8", "H3BMF6", "H3BRA2", "H3BUV0", "A0A669KBL1"]}}, {"query": "ATP1A3", "_id": "478", "_score": 93.2793, "uniprot": {"Swiss-Prot": "P13637", "TrEMBL": ["M0R116", "Q53ES0", "A0A0A0MT26", "M0QXF2"]}}, {"query": "ASH1L", "_id": "55870", "_score": 87.80293, "uniprot": {"Swiss-Prot": "Q9NR48", "TrEMBL": ["A0A7I2YQU9", "A0A7I2V316", "A0A7I2V3D6", "H0YI82", "A0A7I2V4K0", "A0A7I2YQL4", "F8VWK7", "A0A7I2V542", "A0A7I2V4H9"]}}, {"query": "ANKRD17", "_id": "26057", "_score": 90.394646, "uniprot": {"Swiss-Prot": "O75179", "TrEMBL": ["H0YLQ3", "H0YM23"]}}, {"query": "SMC1A", "_id": "8243", "_score": 89.55028, "uniprot": {"Swiss-Prot": "Q14683", "TrEMBL": ["G8JLG1", "A0A384MR33", "Q68EN4", "A0A6Q8PHC3", "V9GY57", "V9GYN9"]}}]
```

Comment: You're asking how to loop over dictionaries in a list and extract certain values. It's unclear what you want with these values afterwards - print them, save them to a file, store them in some data structure? What have you tried yourself? Did you write any code? Please share what you have and explain where you got stuck, or what part of the problem you cannot solve. Can't read the file? Can't turn the text into a list of dictionaries? Can't loop over the list? Can't read the values from the dictionary? Don't know how to construct the result? Or save it?

Comment: I have a very long text file and I want to extract all the values for the query and Swissprot and save them in the file as two columns, one for the queries and one for the Swiss-Prot

Comment: Do you have Python code you've tried already?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have a json-formatted file. You can read this using the [`json` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html), and process the resulting list of dictionaries to print the output you want.

```
import json

with open("input.txt") as f:
    data = json.load(f)

print("Query\tSwiss-Prot")
for item in data:
    q = item["query"]
    sp = item["uniprot"]["Swiss-Prot"]
    print(f"{q}\t{sp}")
```

Which gives:

```
Query   Swiss-Prot
MED13   Q9UHV7
NIPBL   Q6KC79
```

---

If you have *multiple lines* in your input file which are all separately json-formatted, you could use the following to parse your file. Here, I read each line from the file, parse the json, and add all the elements of the resulting list to the `data` list. The code to print the output remains the same.

```
import json

data = []
with open("input.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        data.extend(json.loads(line))
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried but I got this error: q = item["query"]
TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: @anita then the text you have provided is not a representative example of your input file. Please provide an example that is representative of your entire input file.

Comment: @anita, this is why you should share some of your code and preferably a sample of the original source data, so that people can see what you're working with, instead of having to guess.

Answer (score 1):

```
# import json for converting your text file
import json

# open your text file
with open("yourfile.txt", "r") as file:
    data = file.read()

# convert your data to json (dictionary)
convert_to_dict = json.loads(data)

# loop through the dict file and print the results
for i in convert_to_dict:
    print(i["query"], " ", i["uniprot"]["Swiss-Prot"])
```

Answer (score 0):

Your datas are in a list with a dictionnary for each entry. Iterate with a loop over entries and extract values.

```
print("Query\tSwiss-Prot")

for entry in datas:
    if 'query' in entry:
        if ('uniprot' in entry) and ('Swiss-Prot' in entry['uniprot']):
            print(f"{entry['query']}\t{entry['uniprot']['Swiss-Prot']}")
        else:
            print(f"{entry['query']}\tUnknown")
```